# SSRS report is not showing the data as exected

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to create SSRS report with following information. I have class_name and Class_Location column at the same Level. but, Class has many students and it can be listed once i click + sign on the student names for that class. So, can anyone help witht his report

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you need to do.

1. Delete `Class_Name` and `Class_Location` columns from your report.
2. Make sure you only have `Student_Name` column in the `Details` group of the report.
3. In the `Row Groups` section right click on `Details` group and add a `Parent Group`, which will add an extra line in your report.
4. Drag and Drop `Class_Name` and `Class_Location` columns in to the parent group.
5. At this point your report will show `Student_Name` column grouped by `Class_Name` and `Class_Location` columns.
6. Now comes the part where you want to add the toggle function in your report, go to `Row Groups` section right click on `Details` group and go to `Properties` --> `Visibility` and make the following selections:
   [image]
   `Display can be toggled by this report Item` select your parent group there and it should work.

Comment: Hi Ali,  I want to toggle that report. When you expand Class_name, it should display all the student_name. How can i do that? Also, I don't want to display any student information until we expand the Class. Could you please tell how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Drilldown reports tutorial may help to solve the issue. link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KB1Y4m4Uxw0